Woocommerce: Payment gateway custom thank you page in a WP Network Site
With the following code in a child theme, I redirect the user to a custom Thank You Page instead of the standard thank you page after the payment has been made in PayPal. that works perfectly. But now I have set up a network site with several pages and would like to have its own custom thank you page for each of these network sites. Since the child theme is the same across all network sites, I would have to adapt the code for it. Can I somehow query which network site the order was placed from and then redirect accordingly?
The Network Sites are:
mysite.com/north
mysite.com/south
mysite.com/west
mysite.com/east
 function my_custom_redirect( $order_id ){
     $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
     $url = 'https://cmysite.com/north/thank-you';
     if ( ! $order->has_status( 'failed' ) ) {
         wp_safe_redirect( $url );
         exit;
     }
 }


Using this function you can get the Network site URL:
get_bloginfo( 'url' );
Code will be like this:
     function my_custom_redirect( $order_id ){
     $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
     $url = get_bloginfo( 'url' ) . '/thank-you';
     if ( ! $order->has_status( 'failed' ) ) {
         wp_safe_redirect( $url );
         exit;
     }
 }

